# HTML таблица с изменяемой шириной строки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать таблицу, чтобы можно было менять ее размер, по клику на боковое правое ребро?

Comment: Что значит "как"? Вам этапы разработки описать?)

Comment: Ну если данный вопрос, в вашем понимании, тянет на отдельную разработку, то да. А для нормальных людей, необходима наводка куда посмотреть, что бы реализовать данное действие.

Comment: можете посмотреть как сделаны сплиттеры, только там используется mouseUp, mouseDown. А вы будите использовать клик.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Возможно вас натолкнет на мысль вот эта статья:
   [Scaled/Proportional Content with CSS and JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/)
2. В jQuery UI есть специальный плагин [Resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)
3. В крайнем случае можно реализовать простейшее переключение размеров на JS + CSS. Вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/66mmzdod/

```js
var $content = $(".content");
var $corner_button = $(".corner");
var MOD = "big";

$corner_button.on("click", function () {
 toggleBig();
});

function toggleBig () {
 $content.toggleClass(MOD);
}
```

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.content.big {
    width: 500px;
}

.corner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 10px;
    background: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```